# Reducing Run Time Complexity !!! Reducing Nested loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, loops

I am working on the python program which gives/takes standard input/output. The first line gives Number of Test Cases **T**. Second-line gives the size of data **N**. Third and Fourth line gives *space-separated integers* respectively of length **N**. The program arranges Set **A** and **B** that Set **A** has the maximum number of items that are greater than their *equally-indexed* items in Set **B**. Below is my code:

```
 def main():
   T=int(input())
   for ii in range(T):
        N=int(input())
        revo=list(map(int, input().split()))
        star=list(map(int, input().split()))
        win=0
        for i in range(N):
            a=1
            for j in range(revo[i]):
                b=revo[i]-a
                if b in star:
                    win=win+1
                    t=star.remove(b)
                    break
                a=a+1
        print(win)
main()
```

The *inputs* are:

```
1
10
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1
2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6
```

The output is **7** because when arranged optimally Set A has 7 items which are greater than in Set B. But when we input large datasets it took long time to produced output. Is there any better functions that I can use to Reduce Run Time?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is `O(k*n^2)`, which is really a lot.

```
 def main():
   T=int(input())
   for ii in range(T): # ignoring number of inputs in time complexity
        N=int(input())
        revo=list(map(int, input().split())) # O(n), doesn't matter
        star=list(map(int, input().split())) # O(n), doesn't matter
        win=0
        for i in range(N): # n
            a=1
            for j in range(revo[i]): # n*k, k depends on 
                                     # how big is each number, hard to tell
                b=revo[i]-a
                if b in star: # k*n^2
                    win=win+1
                    t=star.remove(b) # normally this would multiply by n, but
                                     # remove can be called at most n times 
                    break
                a=a+1
        print(win)
main()
```

You could gown down to `O(nlogn)` if you sorted both lists first. Here's my solution:

```
def solve(list1, list2):
    list1 = sorted(list1) # n*logn
    list2 = sorted(list2) # 2*n*logn
    pos_in_list1, pos_in_list2 = 0, 0
    while pos_in_list1 < len(list1): # 2*n*logn + n
        if list1[pos_in_list1] > list2[pos_in_list2]:
            pos_in_list1 += 1
            pos_in_list2 += 1
        else:
            pos_in_list1 += 1
    return pos_in_list2


print(solve([3, 6, 7, 5, 3, 5, 6, 2, 9, 1], [2, 7, 0, 9, 3, 6, 0, 6, 2, 6]))
# 7


def main():
    _ = input()  # we don't need n
    list1 = [int(i) for i in input().split()] # O(n), doesn't matter
    list2 = [int(i) for i in input().split()] # O(n), doesn't matter
    print(solve(list1, list2))
```

`O(2*n*logn + n) = O(nlogn)`

Comment: that's a good answer, but still, here time complexity is O(NxN), how can we reach up to O(nlogn)

Comment: It's O(nlogn). I'll add comments about complexity

Comment: you have inserted commas <,> in input, that means it became integer, but the input is actually a <str> the integers are only space-separated. First, we have to convert them to integers

Comment: Sure but that's a O(n) operation, i skipped it

Comment: I have just integrated and complied it, it works fine on large data sets. Thank you

Comment: Good answer indeed, though I would argue that the complexity of the first solution is k*n^2 because `t=star.remove(b)` is within a `if` loop, and executed maximum once for each value of `i`

Comment: `star.remove(b)` has to find b in star. Also it will always iterate the whol list, because `list.remove` removes all occurrences.

Comment: Sure but it is still a O(n) operation, that is executed maximum n times during the program, so a total of O(n^2)

Comment: @Tawy ya you are right. Is there any better solution for time reduction

Comment: @VIKAS There is no better *generic* solution for this problem AFAIK. If your program is still too slow, you will need to provide more detailed explanations for us to help you (Provide actual inputs for which the program is too slow, explain why you need to solve this problem so that maybe we can come up with an alternative, etc...)